# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker - While updating identitymodel table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm trying to update a custom field in identitymodel, called EkipaId.

```
      public ActionResult JoinTeam(int id)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        currentUser.EkipaId = id;
        db.Users.Attach(currentUser);
        db.Entry(currentUser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Ekipa", "Home");
    }
```

I go to url/Home/JoinTeam/1 and I get an exception.
I find the current user, and set the EkipaId to the Id that was in the url.
I get "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

I read about detaching objects, but It is not attached before.

Comment: Do you get it first time you run? You are not disposing your DbContext which will cause issues when running it multiple times. Edit: Also pass your created context `db` into your `UserManager`

Comment: Yes, I get it the first time I run it. How do I pass it to usermanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispose your DbContext and also have the UserManager use the same instance. Something like this:

```
public ActionResult JoinTeam(int id)
{
    using(ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        currentUser.EkipaId = id;
        db.Users.Attach(currentUser);
        db.Entry(currentUser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Ekipa", "Home");
    }
}
```

However creating DbContext like this is not encouraged. Have a look at dependency injection in ASP.Net https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection